# Im using cypress as test software and im trying get it work with openstreetmap (sry for bad english)

Tags: cypress, openstreetmap

Im an apprentice and we have a website and im trying to learn cypress. We got on the site this map from openstreetmap and i cant figure out how i can do it properly. I saw cypress can work with google street maps because they have librarys but not with openstreetmaps.

I tried it with inspect elements but unfortunately it didnt work.

My code:

```
it('Kartentest'), () => {
   cy.contains('Karte').click
   cy.get('#live-view-map')
)}
```

The Error im getting is always "Timed out" but its because cypress cant find the map.
If theres some solution or library i can use it could be helpful. Thank you in advance for your help!